# How can i create log files date wise?

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I am creating logger file .now i need to create logger files based on date.
my below code is creating only one log file .but  i need to create a new 
log file date wise.am not getting any idea how create log files every day.

am using below code for creating log files.

```
  import logging
  from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
  from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
  from time import strftime
  import traceback

  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route("/")
  def get_index():
      return "Welcome to Flask! "

  @app.route("/data")
  def get_hello():
    data = {
        "Name":"Ivan Leon",
        "Occupation":"Software Developer",
        "Technologies":"[Python, Flask, MySQL, Android]"
    }
    return jsonify(data)

  @app.route("/error")
  def get_json():
    return non_existent_variable # ---> intentional <---


 @app.after_request
 def after_request(response):
   # this if avoids the duplication of registry in the log,
   # since that 500 is already logged via @app.errorhandler
   if response.status_code != 500:
      ts = strftime('[%Y-%b-%d %H:%M]')
      logger.error('%s %s %s %s %s %s',
              ts,
              request.remote_addr,
              request.method,
              request.scheme,
              request.full_path,
              response.status)
   return response

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def exceptions(e):
   ts = strftime('[%Y-%b-%d %H:%M]')
   tb = traceback.format_exc()
   logger.error('%s %s %s %s %s 5xx INTERNAL SERVER ERROR\n%s',
              ts, 
              request.remote_addr, 
              request.method,
              request.scheme, 
              request.full_path, 
              tb)
   return "Internal Server Error", 500

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   handler = RotatingFileHandler('app.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=3)
   logger = logging.getLogger('__name__')
   logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   logger.addHandler(handler)
   app.run()
```

Comment: please someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Create log file name dynamically each time your code runs.
Somethings like

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
file_name = "app_" + str(now) + ".log"
```

then use this filename in the code instead of "app.log". This will create a log for each time the code runs. If you want it to create a log for each day only, you can use.

```
now = datetime.date.today()
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('a') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\GST-JYOTHI\\Desktop\\error_logs\\PRO-HUB\\app_2017-10-09 10:47:42.321000.log'

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i m getting above error after using your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

def get_logger(filename='', name=''):
    log_file_name = filename
    logging_level = logging.DEBUG
    # set TimedRotatingFileHandler for root
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    # use very short interval for this example, typically 'when' would be 'midnight' and no explicit interval
    handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file_name, when='midnight', backupCount=10)
    handler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d"

    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)  # or pass string to give it a name
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging_level)
    return logger
```

Then you can call this method wherever you want logging.

Answer (score 0):

use this function in the controller--

```
public function getfile(Request $request)
      {
          Log::channel('custom')->info('Happy Bithday');
          
          $data=$request->date;
          // dd($data);
          if(isset($data)){
          // $file= storage_path(). "/logs/custom-2022-01-19.log";   
          $file= storage_path("logs\custom-".$data.".log");  
          if(file_exists($file)){
          return response()->download($file);
    }
    else {
          echo "File is not exit";
    }
      
      }
      else{
           echo "Select The Date";
      }
     
    }
```

these are the route files

```
Route::get('getfile',[FileController::class, 'getfile']);

// this is for the date function
Route::get('/logs',[FileController::class, 'logs'])->name('logs');

Route::post('getfile',[FileController::class, 'getfile'])->name('getfile');
```

this is blade code --

## Date

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('getfile') }}">
      <div class="form-group">
          @csrf
          <label for="country_name">Select Date:</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date"/>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```